# Keep getting redis error on Amazon EC2

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, redis

I just moved my Magento site to Amazon EC2, but keep getting "Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures" error. I've tried to remove the redis configuration from app/etc/local.xml but still get that error.

I also tried to disable all the cache options directly from core_cache_option table. I have no idea how to clean the already cached files. No cache files under var/cache folder as expected and I've tried to flushall from redis-cli command prompt, but still keep getting this error.

Any idea what else should I try?

```
<cache>
  <backend_options>
    <server><![CDATA[/var/tmp/_cache.sock]]></server>
    <port><![CDATA[0]]></port>
    <persistent><![CDATA[]]></persistent>
    <database><![CDATA[0]]></database>
    <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
    <connect_retries><![CDATA[1]]></connect_retries>
    <read_timeout><![CDATA[10]]></read_timeout>
    <automatic_cleaning_factor><![CDATA[0]]></automatic_cleaning_factor>
    <compress_data><![CDATA[1]]></compress_data>
    <compress_tags><![CDATA[1]]></compress_tags>
    <compress_threshold><![CDATA[20480]]></compress_threshold>
    <compression_lib><![CDATA[gzip]]></compression_lib>
    <use_lua><![CDATA[0]]></use_lua>
  </backend_options>
  <backend><![CDATA[Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis]]></backend>
</cache>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given EC2 instances are ephemeral, you should be able to regenerate the instance, right?  If that's not an option —

First, Check `app/etc/` for **other** XML files.  Magento will parse **any** XML files it finds in this folder.  I've seen something like the following trip people up

```
$ ls app/etc/*.xml
local.xml
local.backup.xml
```

Magento parses both `local.xml` and `local.backup.xml`, and the backup values override the new values in `local.xml`.  Also, make sure you're working with the `local.xml` you think you are.  Magento loads the local configuration in the following location.  Add some temporary debugging to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
public function loadBase()
{
    $etcDir = $this->getOptions()->getEtcDir();
    $files = glob($etcDir.DS.'*.xml');
    $this->loadFile(current($files));
    while ($file = next($files)) {
        var_dump($file);
        $merge = clone $this->_prototype;
        $merge->loadFile($file);
        $this->extend($merge);
    }
    if (in_array($etcDir.DS.'local.xml', $files)) {
        $this->_isLocalConfigLoaded = true;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Second, after you clear your cache, make sure Magento's reloading the configuration.  Add some temporary debugging to

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
public function init($options=array())
{
    $this->setCacheChecksum(null);
    $this->_cacheLoadedSections = array();
    $this->setOptions($options);
    $this->loadBase();

    $cacheLoad = $this->loadModulesCache();
    if ($cacheLoad) {
        var_dump("Loaded Config from Cache");
        return $this;
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump("Reloading configuration");     
    }

    $this->loadModules();
    $this->loadDb();
    $this->saveCache();
    return $this;
}
```

Finally, if you suspect the problem is a file based cache not clearing, drop some debugging code in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php
public function getCacheDir()
{
    //$dir = $this->getDataSetDefault('cache_dir', $this->getVarDir().DS.'cache');
    $dir = $this->_data['cache_dir'];
    $this->createDirIfNotExists($dir);
    var_dump($dir);
    return $dir;
}
```

This will let you know the cache directory Magento's reading from — if Magento can't read the local `var`, it'll pop up to the root level `/var/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. You're the man! You're right, I did make a backup of the local.xml and put it on the same folder. I thought Magento will only read from local.xml. Everything works fine now including the redis. Thanks so much!.